# Bootstrap no column width

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

With bootstrap I need an element to be half the container width in a mobile view so I have added the class 'col-xs-6'. However when the view port increases to tablet view (sm) I want bootstrap to no longer be used at all for that element. Is there a bootstrap class that handles this or do I have to customise my css to do this for me? Thanks.

Comment: do you want it to be 100% width on sm? - .col-sm-12?

Comment: What do you want to happen?

Comment: I want it to act like no bootstrap class has been applied. So currently it is `<div id="basket-checkout" class="col-xs-6"></div>` but when the view port goes to tablet I want it to become styled like it would if the element was this `<div id="basket-checkout"></div>` I know I can remove the bootstrap class with JS when the view port widens to tablet but I would rather avoid this if bootstrap has a class for it. Thanks.

Comment: There's no way to do this. Even if you removed the class, it would just cause the element to take up 100% of the width of the Bootstrap container. You would have to unload the Bootstrap CSS file completely if you wanted it to not use Bootstrap. I think @TomChew-headMillard comment is what you are looking for.

Comment: I'm agree with @TomChew-headMillard, believe me it's the better solution. Add the class 'col-sm-12' will have the same effect than a div. Without Boostrap, a div is displaying as block, so the whole width... (col-xx-12)

Comment: *I know I can remove the bootstrap class with JS when the view port widens to tablet but I would rather avoid this if bootstrap has a class for it.* Since you don't want to use JS/jQuery, creating a custom `@media` query would be the best solution.

Comment: @YenneInfo my element is inline-block and sits along side others in a 100% width bar. I think I will have to use Chris' idea and use a media query for this.